# Hapijs route registration pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

As the "Inert" plugin now has to be loaded separately. I want to register the routes of my application. I have 2 choices

1) Export a function that takes "server" as an argument and write code as

```
module.exports = function(server) {
    server.register('inert', function(err) {});

    server.routes([....]);
}
```

And simply call it from server.js as `require('./routes.js')(serverObj)`

2) Export the routing mechanism as a hapi plugin

```
exports.register = function(server, opts, next) {
    server.register('inert', function(err) {});

    server.routes([....]);

    next();
}
```

and call it from server.js as `server.register(require('./routes.js'), function(err) {});`

Which is a better / more standardized approach ? OR is there a 3rd way I don't know about.

Side Q: Also, should I register the 'inert' plugin before calling the route function / plugin in the server.js file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.route()` can be passed an array of routes so you could simply export routes as an array:

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            ...
        }
    },
    ...
];
```

And then require that file when you're doing the main app setup:

**index.js**

```
server.register(require('inert'), function (err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route(require('./routes'));
    server.start(...)
});
```

**Side Q: Also, should I register the 'inert' plugin before calling the route function / plugin in the server.js file ?**

Yes, if you're using the [`file`](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#the-file-handler) handler or the [`directory`](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#the-directory-handler) handler, you need to make sure inert is loaded first, otherwise you'll get an error when registering the routes.

If you choose to register routes in a plugin that depends on these handlers, you can use [`server.dependency()`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverdependencydependencies-after) to express this dependency and delay registering the routes until inert is loaded. This means you don't have to care about which order you list your plugins in `server.register()`. Useful if you're working with lots of plugins or on a big application/team.